# sql both ALTER and INSERT with same python placeholder

Tags: python, sql, xml, sqlite, elementtree

I would like to parse a xml document with python and create a database out of it (using sqlite3).

The xml.tag will create rows, the xml.text will be the data in the row.

The xml (part of it) :

```
<intrants>
<PPPs>
<PPP>
<titulaire ref-type="firme-titulaire" ref id="20110427000619000001">DUPONT SOLUTIONS (FRANCE) S.A.S.</titulaire>
<type-produit>PPP</type-produit>
<etat-produit>AUTORISE</etat-produit>
<numero-AMM>9600509</numero-AMM>
```

The code :

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("PPPsdb.sqlite")
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.executescript('''
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PPP (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE);
''')

fname = "C:blablabla.xml"

tree = ET.parse(fname)

root = tree.getroot()

all = root.findall('intrants/PPPs/PPP/') 

if one.find(".//") is None :
    if one.find(".").text is not None : print one.find(".").text, len(one.find(".").text)

    try :
        print one.tag.replace("-", "_")
        print one.text

        cur.execute(''' 
            ALTER TABLE PPP ADD COLUMN ''' + (one.tag.replace("-", "_")))


        cur.execute(''' INSERT OR IGNORE INTO PPP (titulaire)
            VALUES ( ? )''', (one.text,))

    except : 
        continue

conn.commit()
```

This code does not work but it runs (no traceback).

I would like the placeholder to assign values to both the column title and its very own data.

For extra info, this code is only supposed to run if the column to be created does not already exists (but that is not the purpose of this post).

Comment: ** I said "child data" in the post, I meant the .text content in the xml file (not the child to that node if exists)

Comment: Please try to edit your question instead of adding comment.

Comment: Interesting that no error is raised as you are attempting to parameterize a column identifier and have an extra parameter in `execute` that is not part of *params* due to mismatched parentheses. Please post *blablabla.xml* for a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Of course, too, there are no commits.

Comment: conn.commit is at the end of the code